# How to return info from different column, same row with Pandas table in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to determine the names of the boroughs with the highest/lowest populations and population densities and the largest/smallest areas. [This is a screenshot of my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjJv.png)

I am able to print these values on their own but don't know how to determine the names of the boroughs they correspond to.

```
maxpop = table.population.max
minpop = table.population.min
maxden = table.density.max
minden = table.density.min
maxar = table.area.max
minar = table.area.min

for item in table:
     if int(item['population']) == int(maxpop):
          result = item['name']
print(result)
```

I then get a TypeError because 'string indices must be integers.' But I don't even know if this is the right way to go about it? Please help!!

Comment: i don't think that `for item in table:` is doing what you think it is..

Comment: What's it doing?

Comment: what do you think it is doing? try printing `item` and see

Comment: yeah, didn't do... anything lol

Comment: does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: haha, i think you may overestimate my coding abilities!! i don't really understand most of what's going on in that post, but thank you so much for trying to help :-)